# How to make the date type be defined as Date, and not as String?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

In my json there is a field with the value "01.05.2021 00:00:00", I need the type to be defined as Date, but it is defined as "String" because of the quotes, apparently. How do I make sure the type is "Date" and not String? I can change String to Date, but how can I do it in the list obtained from JSON?

Example as now:
value 01.05.2021 00:00:00 typeMap String
value 6 typeMap Integer

```
   def getTypeDef(def value) {
        (value instanceof BigDecimal) ? "Double" : value.getClass().simpleName
    }
```

```
 def list = jsonSlurper.parseText JSON
 def typeMap = [:].withDefault { key -> "String" }
            list.each { map ->
                map.each { key, values ->
                    if (values != null) {
                        typeMap[key] = getTypeDef(values)
                        println('value ' + values + ' typeMap ' + typeMap[key])
                        //typeMap[key] = values.getClass().simpleName
                    }
                }
            }
def types = names.collect { name -> typeMap[name] }
```

I can do it like this, but the problem is that the value will still be a string, not a date, but I will get Date in println.

```
    def getTypeDef(def value) {
        if (value ==~ /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\/\-.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\\/\-.]\d{4}\s[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\u0024/){
            (value instanceof String) ? "Date" : value.getClass().simpleName
        }
        else{
            (value instanceof BigDecimal) ? "Double" : value.getClass().simpleName
        }

    }
```

Comment: You parse the JSON into a POJO, where every field has a declared type. The date field should also be annotated with the date format, e.g. in your case that would be `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"` or `"MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use LocalDateTime.parse method?

Comment: I don't understand how this is done, can you give an example if the code is small?

Comment: Show the output of `println('value ' + values + ' typeMap ' + typeMap[key])`, please

Comment: What is the exact format of your list? (strong types?)

Comment: value 0003308549 typeMap String
value 2 typeMap Integer
value 2 typeMap Integer
value 01.07.2021 00:00:00 typeMap String
value 6 typeMap Integer

Comment: @Ekz0, please edit your question and provide a sample input and expected output. json does not support type date. so, you could guess the date in string value by matching it or by parsing.

Comment: def list = jsonSlurper.parseText JSON
I have a list that has a map in it and I need to change the value with a date mask from a string to a date in this list.

Comment: It's still unclear exactly how (and which types) your input types are nestled in each other. Be more specific, please.

Comment: @bimjhi Json has only integer and string. I have a "list", inside which "map", I did not attach data, because they can be any. The question is that I have a date inside this "list" of type "String", how can I change to type "Date"? In the code list.each and map.each, values at a certain step there will be a date value of type String, how can I change it to Date?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to convert a String being in a "2020.04.19 12:10:36" format to Date type.

Input:

```
def date = convertStringToDate("2020.04.19 12:10:36")
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
println sdf.format(date)
```

Output:

```
2020.04.19 12:10:36
```

Code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;  
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

def convertStringToDate(String str) {
    //needed format: String dateStr = "2020.04.19 12:10:36";
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, pattern);
    Date convertedDatetime = Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    assert convertedDatetime instanceof Date
    return convertedDatetime
}
assert convertStringToDate("2020.04.19 12:10:36") instanceof Date

def date = convertStringToDate("2020.04.19 12:10:36")
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
println sdf.format(date)
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how I can change the value from String to Date in the list. I can just replace String with Date, but there is a key-value pair in the list and I need to replace the values in it.